# Sparkling wine from Spain, is it Cava or not?

Tags: wine

I bought a bottle of `Raventos i Blanc` `L'Hereu`. Here is the link to official web site: [Raventos i blanc](http://www.raventos.com/en/press/col_hereu_eng).

I am unsure whether it is Cava or just regular sparkling wine? I know, Spain has strict laws, and it defines conditions to wine manufactures. I don't see any "Cava" word on official web site, and even on the label of the bottle. But there are many photos in the web with older vintage (for example 2008 or 2010) and its label has "Cava". I am confused. Does this mean, this manufacturer cannot label his wines with "Cava" anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into their website and they are moving away from the Cava distinction because it is associated with cheap sparkling wine and they want to go higher end. They could call it Cava but choose not too. I would put this wine at the same level as a nice Champagne. Looks like a really nice bottle of wine!

If you dig further on their website, you'll read this:

> In 1888, Manuel Raventós Doménech created a sparkling wine in Penedés with three native varieties: Xarel•lo, Macabeu and Parellada.
>   When we created CAVA in 1872, we dreamed of a World Class sparkling wine. This is why Josep Raventós Fatjó decided to innovate with Xarel.lo from the same vineyard where de la Finca comes from to this day. He understood the great potential of this grape, the mineral structure of our oldest soils and, most importantly, that to become World Class you have to be AUTHENTIC.
>   **After 150 years CAVA has become a volume-oriented DO lacking geographical distinction in terms of climate and terroir; it also suffers from low viticultural standards.... For this reason, in November 2012 we decided to leave the CAVA DO.**
>   We believe that we need to create a LOCAL, VITICULTURALLYORIENTED DO with strict controls in order to showcase our wines and help them to be better understood worldwide.